# How to pass value to another activity with id of the option clicked from dialog box

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I have a ListView which is display several String when i click on a categories it will call and pop out a dialog options menu which has the options of English, Hindi and Cancel. The onClicklistener will be triggered when the user Click one of the category from the Listview such as "Novel", "Book" or "Plays".
What I want to do here is, when the user clicks "Book" and choose language English option, I want to pass category_id and language_id to the next activity.the category_id and language_id are the json object that i got from the server response. So I need to get the category_id selected from listview and pass it to the next activity along with the language_id as seleceted in dialog box.

if this is possible then how? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
holder.imageView.setImageUrl(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL+category.getImage(), imageLoader);
    holder.textViewName.setText(category.getName());
    category_id = category.getId();
    language_id = category.getLanguage_id();
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            handleLanguageDialog();

            }

    });


}

private AlertDialog handleLanguageDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Select Language")
            .setItems(R.array.lang, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()                 {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                    // of the selected item
                    switch(which)
                    {
                        case 0:// English


                            break;
                        case 1://Bengali

                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
    return builder.create().show();
}
```

categ.java

```
    private String id;
private String name;
private String description;
private String image;
private String parent_id;
private String language_id;
private String created;
private String modified;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Categ{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", image='" + image + '\'' +
            ", parent_id='" + parent_id + '\'' +
            ", language_id='" + language_id + '\'' +
            ", created='" + created + '\'' +
            ", modified='" + modified + '\'' +
            '}';
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public String getImage() {
    return image;
}
public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
public String getParent_id() {
    return parent_id;
}
public void setParent_id(String parent_id) {
    this.parent_id = parent_id;
}
public String getLanguage_id() {
    return language_id;
}
public void setLanguage_id(String language_id) {
    this.language_id = language_id;
}
public String getCreated() {
    return created;
}
public void setCreated(String created) {
    this.created = created;
}
public String getModified() {
    return modified;
}
public void setModified(String modified) {
    this.modified = modified;
}
```

}

Comment: what are you having difficulty in? getting the category_id and language_id OR passing them to the next activity

Comment: passing them to the next activity...i want to pass category_id of book and language_id of selected language to the next activity when i select language option from dialog.so that it will give me all the books available in that language only

Comment: are you familiar with Intent????

Comment: use Intent and pass your ID into Intent object...using  intent.putExtra();

Comment: yes,I am familiar with intent

Comment: I am getting the id by using language_id = category.getLanguage_id(); and it gives me all the language_id.(e.g 1,2) so if i select english the id passed should be 1 if hindi then id passed should be 2.how can i do this??

Comment: then  its problem on your Method  getLanguage_id();

Comment: you have to clear your method...which gives you all LanguageId. put WHERE clause in your method.

Comment: can you explain it in bit detail??Sagar Aghara

Comment: `handleLanguageDialog();` this method is returning an alert dialog....you are not showing the dialog anywhere

Comment: yeah tht was an error earlier but i have corrected tht....and now updated here also

Comment: still the problem exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first activity pass data like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("CATEGORY_ID", category_id);
intent.putExtra("LANGUAGE_ID", language_id);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now in your next activity recieve data like this

```
String cat_id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("CATEGORY_ID");
String cat_id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("LANGUAGE_ID");
```

Comment: It will pass the value for sure...but suppose...i clicked on english and its id is 1 so will it pass the id=1??

Comment: it will pass whatever is stored in the variables category_id and language_id.....you must store the values you want to pass in these variables.....if you want help with that let me know i'll update my answer

Comment: yes i need help becoz in language_id all the language id are stored and in category id all the categoreis id are stored....i need to separate it...plss help me...how can i do it??so that it will pass only the selected category_id and language_id to the next activity and shows the result accordingly

Comment: is category_id variable a string?

Comment: so you already have category_id with this statement `category_id = category.getId();` now you can get your laguage id in your case statement like this. `case 0:` `language_id = yourArrayOfLanguageIDs.get(which);` and pass them as i told in the answer

Comment: I have both...category_id = category.getId();
        language_id = category.getLanguage_id(); like this....languge id have the value of all languages ids.(i.e-1,2) and category id have all the ids of category(i.e-1,2,3,4,5,6).

Comment: and this all the values are coming from server response through json

Comment: okay so in case statement do this for case 0, `intent.putExtra("LANGUAGE_ID", "English");`

Comment: will it be same for hindi also??and what about category_ids??becoz i have to pass both at a time for the result to be like....all books list in selected language

Comment: same for hindi in case 1: `intent.putExtra("LANGUAGE_ID", "Hindi");` and yes you can pass both at the same time as written in the answer.... i hope its clear now????

Comment: its not working ...it is always taking language_id =1 and category_id= 3

Answer (score 0):

Pass like this inside your switch case

```
case 0:
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, Destination.class);
intent.putExtra("category_key", category_id);
intent.putExtra("language_key", language_id);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(SourceActivity.this,destinationAvtivity.java);
    intent.putExtra("category_id",109);
    startActivity(theintent);
```